# How to add validation rule for a field to update first and restrict to edit second time

Tags: custom-field, validation-rule

I've a requirement on pick-list field that field can allow to insert a value for first time and if the user try to insert a value second time that should through an error message.how can i achieve this.

Comment: I would say create a hidden checkbox and on the first update - write a WF to check the checkbox and now write a validation something like - AND( ISCHANGED(picklist), Checkbox)

Comment: If you are talking about updating the picklist just use ISCHANGED(), ISCHANGED wont fire on insert. you cannot insert the value second time, your second time insert is technically an update unless you are talking about deleting the record and reinserting again.

Comment: Hi Sanjay,thanks for quick reply.Can't we achieve this without Workflows?

Comment: I think what @Rao mentioned makes sence, since ISCHANGED() wont fire on the intial insert and only fires on an update on the picklist. It should work try ISCHANGED(Picklist__c) as the validation criteria and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to check the PriorValue of the field along with IsChanged so that as long as the picklist value remains blank, i.e., the picklist value is not selected the first time, the system will allow the record to update the picklist value. But if the picklist value has been set, i.e., it is no longer blank, then the validation rule throw up an error.

Assuming the name of the field is `Type`, the following validation rule should work.

```
AND( 
    NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Type))), 
    ISCHANGED(Type) 
)
```

Based on your comment, added the condition to check for profile.

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Type))), 
    ISCHANGED(Type),
    NOT( $Profile.Name = 'System Administrator')
)
```

Comment: One doubt,Is there any possibility that only System Admin can edit this field for second time after using this Validation rule?

Comment: @User1511, Have updated my answer to exclude the system admin from the validation rule.

Comment: Hey Thanks Man,you are awesome.Its working as expected.